# LaTeX can't find fontsetup non-free .sty files - MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, windows

I was trying to recompile a document I have already used in the past, and I found that my miktex installation can't find fontsetup non-free files (.sty).

I am using MiKTeX on Windows 10.

This is my MWE (or used to work):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[cambria]{fontsetup}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
File `fspcambria.tex' not found. \AtBeginDocument
```

What I have already tried:

- Open MiKTeX console and check if fontsetup non-free and fontsetup is installed.
- Change latexmk to lualatex and xelatex
- Uninstall and reinstall fontsetup and fontsetup non-free
- Manually find the .sty files (they are where they are supposed to be)
- Update file name database in the MiKTeX console.

[image: files]

[image: files2]

Comment: The error speaks about a tex file and that's obviously not there.

Comment: Why it is asking for a .tex file? I opened fontsetup and the related line says: ``\DeclareOption{cambria}{\input{fspcambria}}`  and no `.tex` is explicitly indicated.

Comment: Ok, apparently there is a mismatch between fontsetup and fontsetup nonfree files in the MiKTeX repository and the CTAN. I manually downloaded from CTAN and is now working. I wonder why the behaviour changed now, after it used to work a few months ago.

Comment: Input always looks for tex if there is no extension. Check if you have the package fontsetup-nonfree installed. If yes check its content and if the file is missing report it to miktex.

Comment: the posted code doesn't ask for cambria at all though, do you really get that error from the document shown?

Comment: @David Carlisle. I updated the code. My bad I was trying using the free version of fontsetup and it worked without problems, but no free fonts didn't. Anyway I found the solution and is a problem in the miktex version of `fontspec-nonfree`  . The CTAN version includes .tex files, while the MiKTeX version uses .sty. I manually overwrite my installation with the CTAN files and now it is working as intented.